# Group Policy Event id

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-event-log

DC - Windows Server 2008 R2

Client OS - Window XP

Which Event id is generated on Window XP, if my Group policy preference is automatically updated after 90 minutes interval.

Sorry, i tried to find out through google, but unable to find exact event id

Answer (score 3):

Computer: 8006, User: 8007.  The logs are in the Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Group Policy\Operational event log.

https://blogs.technet.com/b/gpguru/archive/2008/08/29/troubleshooting-group-policy-using-event-logs.aspx

```
8000 Successful computer end event

8001 Successful user end event

8002 Successful computer network change event

8003 Successful user network change event

8004 Successful computer manual refresh event

8005 Successful user manual refresh event

8006 Successful computer periodic refresh event

8007 Successful user periodic refresh event
```

Comment: Thank you very much Greg, It would be great help, if you can also guide for Window XP Operating System. What Event id is generated on Windows XP machine